# Android browser file not downloading from linux server

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, apache-2.4

I have two linux servers with domains i.e `redsignal.net` and `eventbuizz.com`

I have uploaded same PDF files on both servers.

[PDF file on redsignal.net](http://www.redsignal.net/sample.pdf)

[PDF file on eventbuizz.com](http://eventbuizz.com/conference_demo/sample.pdf)

When I open first link on `Android` mobile's browser it starts downloading and after downloading you can open this PDF in any supported app installed on the phone.

The problem is when I open 2nd link on `Android` mobile's browser it starts downloading but never completes. It just shows loading in notification center and never finishes.

You can check both links are working on all devices, desktop, iPhone.

I have googled this issue and found there must be some server side settings to resolve this but none of those settings worked for me. I have tried different `.htaccess` configuration but no luck.

**Note:** This issue is not on all `Android` mobiles, its with `Android` versions 4.0.4 and earlier. On same `Android` mobile if I open pdf file from other servers it works. So that's why I think there must be some server side settings to resolve this issue.

Comment: I've noticed that using server1 the file opens in brower, using server2 it is downloaded : i think server1 does not know the mime type for pdf but server2 knows. You may have `AddType application/octet-stream .pdf` somewhere in your `Apache` config for server2 that you could try yo remove.

Comment: I did it. server2 is downloading because I added following in .htaccess to resolve this issue but still no luck. <Files *.pdf>
 ForceType application/octet-stream
 Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>

Comment: Do you mean it does not work either if you remove this ?

Comment: @krisFR yes it doesn't work if i remove this.